# In-app purchase, show products but nothing happens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement IAPs in one app but I'm still having difficulties with it. I followed various tutorials but all of them are out of date and full of errors. The only one that could work that I found is [this one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-in-app-purchases/):

But I'm having a problem, the 3 products appear on my tableview but then when I click on one of them nothing happens... cell become blue and that's all... Am I missing something?

Or is that tutorial incomplete?

How do I run the purchase attempt?

Here is my code:

```
   -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
     {
      [productDetailsList addObjectsFromArray: response.products];
      [productDisplayTableView reloadData];
     }


     -(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
      {
         NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
       }    


       - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
       {
        return [self.productDetailsList count];
       }
       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
           static NSString *GenericTableIdentifier = @"GenericTableIdentifier";
           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: GenericTableIdentifier];
           if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: GenericTableIdentifier];
           }
           NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
           SKProduct *thisProduct = [productDetailsList objectAtIndex:row];
           [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",            thisProduct.localizedTitle, thisProduct.price]];
           return cell;
       }



        - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
           productDetailsList    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
           productIdentifierList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
           for (short item_count=1; item_count <= 5; item_count++) {
               [productIdentifierList addObject:[NSString              stringWithFormat:@"com.mycompany.myapp.%d", item_count]];
           }
           SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifierList]];
           request.delegate = self;
           [request start];

           [super viewDidLoad];
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
       }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Dude, post your tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have something in the lines of:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
    SKProduct *selectedProduct = [self.productDetailsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
}
```

Apple provides a decent [step by step guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html) for handling in app purchases.

Answer (score 1):

The main way to run IAPs involves a few different methods, but there are a few different steps you need to follow when implementing IAPs.

The first of these requirements are protocols. Please include each of the following protocols in your header file.

- SKProductsRequestDelegate
- SKPaymentTransactionObserver
- SKRequestDelegate

You need the request methods:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    if(response.products.count > 0)
    {
        SKProduct* product;

        for(int i = 0; i<response.products.count; i++)
        {
            product = [response.products objectAtIndex:i];

            if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"product identifier"])
            {
                self.currentProduct = product;
                [self beginPaymentWithProduct:product];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the if statement to keep track of which product was being purchased. You will need an if-statement in that for-loop for each product identifier if you have multiple products. Use this later to unlock whatever on completion of the purchase.

You will also need the beginPayment method:

```
- (void)beginPaymentWithProduct:(SKProduct*)product
{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

You also need the payment processing methods. I will not post all of them here as this would take far too much space, but I will give you the prototypes.

```
-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request;
-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful;
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
```

For each of your buttons in your table that are supposed to be purchasing, they will need to perform a method similar to this one on the `didSelectRowAtIndex...` method:

```
- (void)buyCoins:(id)sender
{
    if([self canMakePurchases])
    {
        ualRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"product identifier", nil]]];
        [ualRequest setDelegate:self];
        [ualRequest start];
    }
}
```

This method will run the product request successfully. If you have all of these components in, you should have no problems.

I have used this code successfully in several apps.

Comment: Thx for that, it is a different approach and probably it is better for my purpose... but right answare for my case came from beeBee